# Developing Laurent series on three types of regions: centered at the origin, and non-centered at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

So, in lieu of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348500/how-to-grasp-the-relationship-between-laurent-series-depending-on-the-region-the/4348928?noredirect=1#comment9076396_4348928) post, I want to deepen the discussion of the Laurent series. We have the Laurent theorem:

*If f(z) is analytic on $R_1\leq |z-z_o|\leq 2$, then $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$*

Take for example the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{2-z}$, and develop it into series on the ring $0\leq|z|\leq 2$. First we see that the **pole z=2 is within**  the region, so we develop this into a **Power series** (in the form of  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2-z}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-z/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n(z/2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}
\end{equation}

Then we have another case, where the same function is to be developed into a series in the region $0\leq|z|\leq1$: Here, clearly the pole $z=2$ is outside of this region, but since $|z-2|\leq 1$, **it still satisfies the boundary** of the region, so we **still develop it into a Power series.**

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2-z}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-z/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n(z/2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}
\end{equation}

Then we have the more in-obvious case, develop the function into a series on the annulus centered at $z_0=1$, that is  $2\leq|z-1|\leq3$. This annulus  has the pole of f(z) at its limit point, so we ideally still seek a Power series expansion, if I am not wrong. But since $|z-2|\leq 1 \notin 2\leq|z-1|\leq3 $, we have to develop this function into a Laurent series.

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2-z}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-z/2}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z}\bigg(-\frac{1}{1/2-1/z}\bigg) =\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{2}\bigg(-\frac{1}{1-2/z}\bigg)
\end{equation}

Since we have the form of $a_n/z$ in the last term of the denominator, we can set up the Laurent series:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-2/z}\bigg)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n\bigg(\frac{1}{2^2}\frac{1}{z}\frac{2}{z}\bigg)^n=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n\bigg(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}z^{n+1}}\bigg)
\end{equation}

At this point, we need to respect the form of the boundary of the annulus and the theorem on top, and insert for z=|z-1| and correct the index.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2^{n}(z-1)^{n}}\bigg)
\end{equation}

Would this be correct, and if not, can you explain case by case , why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not correct in what concerns the development into Lauren series in the annulus $2<|z-1|<3$. For such a $z$ we have\begin{align}\frac1{2-z}&=\frac1{1-(z-1)}\\&=-\frac1{z-1}\frac1{1-\frac1{z-1}}\\&=-\frac1{z-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)^n\\&=-\frac1{z-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z-1)^{-n}\\&=-\frac1{z-1}\sum_{n=-\infty}^0(z-1)^n\\&=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^0(z-1)_{n-1}\\&=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(z-1)^n.\end{align}

Comment: Great. Thanks for this. So how can one know that when a pole is outside an annulus, one has to develop the series in this way, and NOT in the way I did? Because the way I did, seeking the form $b_n/z^n$ is used for several  cases, but why not here?

Comment: The annulus is $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid2<|z-1|<3\}$ and therefore the Laurent series has to be centered at $1$, not at $0$.

Comment: So you seek a fraction which has the form (z-1)  as the variable in a Laurent series from the start? While my error was that I developed the fraction with focus on (2/z) which accounts the pole to be 0, which is clearly not in line with the annulus . So one must seek a variable of the Laurent series which is exactly the same as the annular center, I gather.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and that's what I usually do.